# Single observer with multiple observable

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, observable

I would like to know what would be the implementation with respect to observer design pattern. Like generally we maintain a list of observers in Observable and from its notify we call the update method of the observers.

Now what would be the design in this case? Should i maintain a list of observable in the observers? But then in the update method how i would know which observable has called the update on this observer.

Please share your idea on this.

Thanks,

Comment: You may want to pass an Event object that holds the object that trigger event, use an EventDispatcher as the observer from the multiple observable sources and register the callback for each type of event. Or take look at [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236545/observing-multiple-observables-at-once-network-of-chained-observers)

Comment: The implementation would be identical. The cardinality of observers changes nothing about the pattern. It supports zero or more.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the observable hold a reference to the observer. in your case this mightg be a list. in any case, the first argument to update is the observable.

So this is one way:

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
enum Observables {
    o1,o2
}
class MyObservable extends Observable {
    public MyObservable(Observables observables) {
        this.observables=observables;
    }
    public void setChangedAndNotify(Object object) {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(object);
    }
    final Observables observables;
}
class MyObserver implements Observer {
    @Override public void update(Observable o,Object arg) {
        switch(((MyObservable)o).observables) {
            case o1:
                System.out.println(((MyObservable)o).observables);
                break;
            case o2:
                System.out.println(((MyObservable)o).observables);
                break;
        }
    }
}
class so56200126_single_observer_with_multiple_observable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyObservable myObservable1=new MyObservable(Observables.o1);
        MyObservable myObservable2=new MyObservable(Observables.o2);
        MyObserver myObserver=new MyObserver();
        myObservable1.addObserver(myObserver);
        myObservable2.addObserver(myObserver);
        myObservable1.setChangedAndNotify(null);
        myObservable2.setChangedAndNotify(null);
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
}
```